# Why Python's datetime.time have tzinfo parameter?

Tags: python, datetime, pytz, python-datetime

`datetime`, Python's builtin module, have some classes.

But I can not understand well parameter of `datetime.time` class.

`time` class have `tzinfo` param, default is `None`.

I want to know why `time` class needs timezone information.

In case of `datetime` class, it has `.astimezone` method and we can change data by timezone information. But `time` class have no method like `.astimezone`.

Is it just reserved for `datetime.combine` classmethod? or is there some important story about time and timezone?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know why time class needs timezone information.

I find it useful e.g. if we're dealing with events that occur in the same time regardless of the date (e.g. a scheduled job), and need to display, manipulate and compare, in a different timezone.

### How to get a TZ-aware `datetime.time` object

> **datetime.timetz()**
>
> Return time object with same hour, minute, second,
>   microsecond, and tzinfo attributes. See also method time().

So as for my example use case, I'd pull the `datetime.time` object from my tz-aware `datetime.datetime` object, using `datetime.datetime.timetz()`, which conserves it's `tzinfo`

This would fit in a `datetime.time` object, as opposed to a `datetime.datetime` object that also carries the date information.

> But time class have no method like .astimezone.

### You can't TZ-convert using time only

As for the reason there is no `time.astimezone()`, I think it might be because without a date, it is impossible to guess the effects of DST transitions and other non-fixed UTC offsets.

Answer (score 0):

The `time` class makes use of a `tzinfo` for comparison and operations. For example, 9:00 AM in US/Pacific is not equal to 9:00 AM in US/Eastern. Also, python can raise a TypeError if you are comparing an aware to a naive time, i.e., comparing 9:00 AM in US/Pacific to just "9:00 AM"

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.tzinfo):

> comparison of time to time, where a is considered less than b when a precedes b in time. If one comparand is naive and the other is aware, TypeError is raised if an order comparison is attempted. For equality comparisons, naive instances are never equal to aware instances.